# Ability to remove duplicates records returned from LEFT JOIN in many-to-many tables query

Tags: join, duplicates

I have the following question to ask and maybe you can help with this. I did find similar questions asked here as well, but can't really make out effective way to make it work.

I'm working on this application for a customer using Access database.

1. I have 2 tables, which are many-to-many relation between each other. One table is Grants and another table is Key_People.
2. To support many-to-many relation I created another table called Key_People_To_Grants.
3. To simplify my example here: 
   my Grant table contains: GrantID and GrantName
   my Key_People table contains: KeyPersonID and KeyPersonFName and KeyPersonLName
   my Key_People_To_Grants table contains of course: KeyPersonID and GrantID
4. I'm trying to get all Grants using LEFT JOIN with this query and it works great, I get Grants which are in Key_People_To_Grants table and also other Grants not yet linked to a Key_People, which is as required. This is the query I'm using:

   SELECT Grants.*, Key_People.firstName, Key_People.lastName
   FROM (Grants LEFT JOIN Key_People_To_Grants ON Grants.grantID =
   Key_People_To_Grants.grantID) LEFT JOIN Key_People ON 
   Key_People_To_Grants.keyPersonID = Key_People.personID;

Only issue with this query and as I found out in many posts over the web regarding JOINs, is that it returns duplicated Grants records, if a given Grant is assigned to more than one Key_People.
I tried to use Distinct (as I list in the query below) and it works if I'm only selecting info from Grants table, but as soon as I also ask for Key_People.firstName and Key_People.lastName info, the Distinct of course does not work.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Grants.*, Key_People.firstName, Key_People.lastName
FROM (Grants LEFT JOIN Key_People_To_Grants ON Grants.grantID =
Key_People_To_Grants.grantID) LEFT JOIN Key_People ON 
Key_People_To_Grants.keyPersonID = Key_People.personID;
```

Do you have any advice on how to accomplish getting rid of the duplicate info returned, but still to be able to JOIN on tables in my example?

Thanks a lot

Comment: How do you want to handle grants that have more than one key person?

Comment: The query above is used to show Grants on the Grants page. Grants shown will include ones assigned to Key_Person and also ones are not assigned yet. In reality all Grants should have Key Person assigned, but I made the query use LEFT JOIN to cover cases if Grant is not assigned yet to Key Person.

If a given Grant is assigned to more than one Key_Person, it should be shown one time on Grants view page. 
That is the issue I'm having. 
I need to remove duplication of that Grant which is assigned to multiple Key People. I tried few different options in the query, but couldn't get it working yet.

Comment: Hello James, I think I understand your question now. I will only show top (any key person) on the page where I'm displaying Grants info. So maybe this changes my query a bit, with a use of TOP to remove duplicate Grant record returned?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
SELECT g.*, kp.firstName, kp.lastName
FROM `Grants` g
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT MIN(keyPersonID) AS kpid, grantID 
        FROM key_people_to_grants 
        GROUP BY grantID
) kpg ON kpg.grantID = g.grantID
LEFT JOIN Key_People kp ON kp.personID = kpg.kpid
```

Comment: Thanks a lot James. This query does work and returns grant info only for one of the key_people. I can also use MAX instead of the MIN, but essentially it will give me the same thing.

I originally was thinking to use TOP 1 solution, but that didn't work for me. It was probably issue with my SQL, because it should also work and return only single row for the same grant with multiple key_people.